# How to add more custom methods in HttpRequestMessageExtensions class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new mymethodresponse
                {
                    ID= Idval,
                    Created= false
                }
```

Here how to create more overloads for createresponse method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

1.Create a  HttpRequestMessageExtensions class

```
public static class HttpRequestMessageExtensions
    {
        public static HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse(this HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string TestParas)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = statusCode,
                RequestMessage = request
            };
        }
     }
```

2.In controller like below

```
public class OverloadController : Controller
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Call(HttpRequestMessage RequestMessage)
        {
            return RequestMessage.CreateResponse();//do your staff...

        }
     
    }
```

Result:
[image]